# Problema en servidor http python

Tags: python, http, server, python-3.9

intento hacer un framework de Python para hacer servidores web-http y he creado el archivo **server.py**

el archivo server.py crea un servidor básico de python, pero lo q quiero hacer es q en vez de hacer un `self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))`, el servidor pueda leer un archivo html *(esta ubicado en la carpeta **template**s y se llana **index.html**)* y renderizarlo. Yo hice esto pero no entiendo porque no salio:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080



class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()

        with open("templates/index.html") as file:
            for linea in file:
                self.wfile.write(bytes(linea))

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

a mi me sale esto por favor ayuda:

```
Server started http://localhost:8080
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2022 11:59:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64865)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\server.py", line 425, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\server.py", line 413, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "c:\Users\rodri\Desktop\pruebapy\sever copy.py", line 18, in do_GET
    self.wfile.write(bytes(linea))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
----------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jun/2022 11:59:49] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64866)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\server.py", line 425, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\server.py", line 413, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "c:\Users\rodri\Desktop\pruebapy\sever copy.py", line 18, in do_GET
    self.wfile.write(bytes(linea))
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
----------------------------------------
```

por favor ayuda necesito terminar este trabajo

Comment: @HeytalePazguato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy probable que ese error tenga que ver con la linea `self.wfile.write(bytes(linea))`

`self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head>/html>","utf-8"))`

o

`self.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head></html>".encode("utf-8"))`